# Trying to update a script using vectrosity in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

trying to update this script and I can't figure this one out

This is the code:

```
Vector3[] linePoints = new Vector3[] { blinkParticleInstance.transform.position, blinkParticleFloorInstance.transform.position };

VectorLine line = new VectorLine("MyLine", linePoints, blinkLineMat, blinkLineWidth);
```

This is the error:

> cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Vector3>'

Answer (score 1):

well sounds like `VectorLine` is expecting a `List<Vector3>` but you are passing in a `Vector3[]`.

Just do

```
using System.Linq;

...

Vector3[] linePoints = new Vector3[] { blinkParticleInstance.transform.position, blinkParticleFloorInstance.transform.position };
VectorLine line = new VectorLine("MyLine", linePoints.ToList(), blinkLineMat, blinkLineWidth);
```

or use a list in the first place

```
List<Vector3> linePoints = new List<Vector3> { blinkParticleInstance.transform.position, blinkParticleFloorInstance.transform.position };
VectorLine line = new VectorLine("MyLine", linePoints, blinkLineMat, blinkLineWidth);
```